# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, getelementbyid

I want get element by id but if I'm using the getElementById and passing the correct id so Im getting the error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementById')"

1. List item
   html

```
 <div class="optionRow">
                    <label for="option1"> <input class="option" type="radio" value="a" id="option1" name="option">
                        Option 1 </label>
                </div>
```

JavaScript

```
 allOptions[1].document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML = data.a;
    allOptions[2].document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML = data.b;
    allOptions[3].document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML = data.c;
```

to ask why this error ?

Comment: either delete allOptions or document from your query. of course I assume allOptions is an HTML Node that you can query

Comment: @Deniz Karadağ: Only the `document` offers [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 1):

> to ask why this error ?

Only the `document` object offers the function [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). `id` must be unique and therefore there is no need for a `HTMLElement` version of it.

> Unlike some other element-lookup methods such as
> Document.querySelector() and Document.querySelectorAll(),
> getElementById() is only available as a method of the global document
> object, and not available as a method on all element objects in the
> DOM. Because ID values must be unique throughout the entire document,
> there is no need for "local" versions of the function.

So in your case the correct usage of `getElementById` would be:

```
document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML = data.a;
```

Yet be aware that `input` does not support `innerHTML`. If you want to change the `value` take:

```
document.getElementById('option1').value= data.a;
```

Comment: And **if** you had some reason to only find the element if it was within another element you had a reference to and not if it was elsewhere in the document (a very rare use case with an `id`, but...), you could do `const input = elementYouHave.querySelector("#option1")`. But it's a rare use case.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Not so rare for elements which are not part of the `document` (yet).

Comment: @JavaScript - I don't see how that relates?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Can have a structure aka node with subnodes, which is not part of the DOM yet/anymore and one wants to find an element with a specific `id` in it. Therefore `dcoument.getElementById` does not search those nodes until they.

Comment: @JavaScript - Ah, I see what you mean. Searching a freestanding tree rooted in an element rather than a document.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `allOptions[1].document.getElementById('option1')` to `document.getElementById('option1')`

Because the document object is the root node of the HTML document.
You can call `document` or `window.document`, not from element.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML = data.a;
```

The `document` is the a huge container, holding many informations about the site. Check out this website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById for more information. In it is also a link to the `document` element.

Greetings!